# Godaddy, consume external asp.net SOAP webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, asmx

I have an website hosted on Go daddy, and one of the features in my website is to call external soap web service (asmx), and I try to call the service from my machine it works correctly, but when I call it from the hosted web site, an exception is thrown as below:

**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

and this is how I call the web service:

```
SyriaOrganization.Web.localhost.SMOPushWebService SMOPushWebService = new Web.localhost.SMOPushWebService();
SMOPushWebService.SendPushNotification(entityId, entityValueId, url, titleAr, titleEn, StripTagsRegex(detailsAr), StripTagsRegex(detailsEn));
```

Comment: This looks like a firewall problem. Ensure that you have the necessary ports open in the firewall.

Comment: the external web service is hosted on different server not on my machine, and as i said i tested from my machine and using the below link http://www.soapclient.com/ and its works fine, but when i test from the hosted website it gives me th error.

Comment: I meant there's a firewall problem between the hosted website and the target server.

Comment: i turned the fire wall of on the service server, but the result.

Comment: i'm sorry if i bothering you, but i tried a lot of method without success, so please help me if u can.

Comment: It's the same problem. Packets can't get from your hosted server to the web service server. You just have to find out why not. Note also the problem could be in the opposite direction - from the web service server back to your hosted server.

Comment: What kind of a Hosting plan do you have? Unless you have a VPS plan, its very hard/GoDaddy will NOT let you do otherwise

Comment: Who are you using to Push notifications? I was able to use PubNub on my GoDaddy account without any issues and I have the cheapest hosting plan.